How to do 50-23 in binary with borrowing of 1s and with 1s complement
50 in binary is 110010 and 23 in binary is 10111 and the result = 27 11011 but i'm struggling to get the right result with regards to the  borrowing of 1s method   and with 1s complement of  subtrahend + minuend method . For example when trying to borrow 1s for 0 - 1 for the least significant bit I have to borrow from the 2nd least significant bit  so instead of 1 -1 for the 2nd least significant bit the top 1(that got borrowed already ) becomes 0 and it's 0-1 again and  I have to borrow a 1 from the next  most significant bit that has a 1 at the top then I end up running out of 1s to borrow eventually.
also if you look at the 4th bit for 23 and 50 in binary both are 0s yet in 27 the 4th bit is a 1 , in binary subtraction just like addition it uses the principles of an XOR gate so you only get a 1 output if the inputs are on different levels and if they're the same you get a 0 so how does 0-0 make 1 , it should make 0 but that's clearly not correct for 27 in binary which is 11011.
Also when trying to do binary subtraction using the 1s complement method where the subtrahend has the bits flipped and added to minuend I keep ending up with 58 in binary (111010). I apologize if this is a bad question but i'm really trying to understand binary subtraction to improve my understanding of how an ALU works.

Generally ALUs perform substation in two’s compliment, to avoid the issue of -0 imposed by one’s compliment.

This question may be useful in clarifying, specifically this concise answer.

Two's complement also saves you the trouble of figuring out how to subtract a negative number.
